# Split dictionaries in two array and sort the dictionary by value swift

Tags: swift, dictionary

1) this is first step : I'm asking how to make this dictionary in order by value.

2)second step: I want to split this dictionary in two array, one for value and one for keys thanks

```js
["fruit": 1, "vegie": 13, "money": 46, "Canada": 219, "cash": 1, "lola": 1, "tv": 2, "bed": 1, "sofa": 1]
```

I did something like that but I want to split in two arrays now

```js
let byValue = {
    (elem1:(key: String, val: Int), elem2:(key: String, val: Int))->Bool in
    if elem1.val < elem2.val {
        return true
    } else {
        return false
    }
}
let sortedDict = dict.sort(byValue)
```

Comment: Dictionaries are never in order. Whenever you run a for-each loop or whatever loop, it will pickup values regardless to order. Unless you have a continuous series of Keys, which you can use in a loop like keys 1,2...,10 and using `objectForKey:loopCounter`

Comment: SO you didn't understand my question :), I'm asking how make this dictionary in order by value, this is first step, second step, I want to split this dictionary in two array, one for value and one for keys thanks

Comment: @NSNoob You can help me ?

Comment: You can split the dictionary. I can help you with that. but you cannot create a sorted dictionary.

Comment: For the keys `let keys = sortedDict.map { $0.0 }` and the values `let values = sortedDict.map { $0.1 }`

Comment: What you should do is create an array for keys first. Then sort that array. Then use those sorted keys from array to create an array of values.

Comment: Thanks @awph You are awesome !

Comment: @awph write your answer I will give you points for it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that the part 1 of your question is done as you said in your last edit, here is how to have...

The keys:

```
let keys = sortedDict.map { $0.0 }
```

And the values:

```
let values = sortedDict.map { $0.1 }
```